# How to get Dialogflow to accept my already defined entities?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

first of all I´m really sorry for my bad english. Anyway, the situation is this:

I´m working with DialogFlow to create some kind of "bot" that can answer "Questions" about Fútbol, Football, Soccer

I´d already defined and used similar entities before without any problem.
So this time I proceed to create some entities as you can see here

Entity defined

[image: Entity defined]

Then, when im try to use it in an intent, DialogFlow show me the next error

Entity error

[image: Entity error]

And I have no idea whats wrong, I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first save your entity first before you can use it.

Otherwise you may need to refresh the intents page. It is likely you created the intent and then tried to set up the entity so the intent doesn't know that team_spain_nowin exists yet. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well... thanks, closing the tabs and refresh intent page actually worked